# Analogue of "Is the Pope Catholic?"

Tags: перевод

In English, one way to respond to a question where the answer is obviously yes is to ask back "Is the Pope Catholic?" What is a Russian analogue, i.e., a *conventional* question-as-reply for which the answer is clearly affirmative?

A good answer to this question should work, for instance, in both of the following situations:

1) Replying to "I saw Ivan on the bus to the airport. Is he traveling somewhere?"

2) You are a chemist and someone says to you "There is a username on chemistry.stackexchange that is your first initial and last name. Is that you?"

Comment: Я бы сказал > Спроси меня о чем-то потруднее

Comment: @JacobSeleznev, is that really a widely used conventional phrase for the situation I described?

Comment: Да например: `- Джейк, это мэр. Тебе приходилось слышать что-нибудь о таком явлении
как "трепидация"?
- Спроси что-нибудь потруднее, - ответил городской астроном с
недоумением.`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Usually something like "А как ты думаешь?" (And how do you think?) with a slight accent pointing that the speaking person actually wonders how *else* one can think on such simple question.

But if you mean, if there are more mocking ways to answer some stupid questions, I should say, it depends. But, anyway, in a strictly affirmative form, not in a question-as-reply one. For example, teenager-like slang "Ясен пень!" (Clear stump!) or Odessa-like "Или" (Or).

Comment: I've never heard `или` used this way, I'm not sure it would make sense to people outside Odessa.

Comment: @NikolayErshov Попробуйте почитать это ;-) http://www.ipiran.ru/~shorgin/hamlet.htm

Comment: Please no. I've read just a few lines and I need brain bleach already. And what does it have to do with anything?

Comment: @NikolayErshov Well, just as an example of using the word "Or" (many times).

Comment: All the more of a warning against using it in real life or good writing.

Comment: @NikolayErshov De gustibus non est disputandum.

Comment: hahahahahahahaha

Answer (score 1):

Ещё как!  (Ещё какой, ещё какие etc.)

```
- Твой кот - хулиган?
- Ещё какой!
```

Answer (score 1):

A good answer to your both cases could also be:

> Что за вопрос?

It can mean "Absolutely! You shoudn't have been asked" or that the answer to a question you have just been asked is obviously 'yes'.

Answer (score 1):

More or less neutral way:

> Сам[а]-то как думаешь?

Meaning:

> What do you think?

If you're irritated by blatantly banal or unpleasant question, you could reply with a statement having opposite meaning:

> — Как думаешь, в этом месяце опять задержат зарплату?
>
> — Нет, блять, премию дадут! Ты продажи-то видел?

Meaning:

> — Will the salary get delayed again this month, what do you think?
>
> — Delayed?! No, you'll get a fucking bonus! Have you seen the sales?

(Of course, nobody expects the salary to be paid in time, let alone the bonus)

Comment: Your last sentence seems completely inappropriate.

Comment: Perhaps inappropriate, but GREAT example of real language.